# How to run an android device on an android studios

Tags: android, usb, device

I am currently trying to figure out why my mobile device will not show up in android studios.I have installed the google usb drivers for android studios, and enabled usb debugging. I just have no idea why I can't see the device in android studios.

Comment: What's the device? For example for Huawei devices it is somethimes needed to install [HiSuite](http://consumer.huawei.com/minisite/HiSuite_en/) ...

Comment: Its a motorolla device

Comment: try [this](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to install the device driver. Go to the Device Manager and check it.

Answer (score 0):

'cd' to your sdk platform-tools folder

Check if adb finds your device

```
./adb devices
```

If you do not see your device, restart adb :

```
./adb kill-server
./adb start-server
```

then re-run ./adb devices and see if it finds your device. Example :

```
List of devices attached
3a2b522 device
```